# Naive height of zero

Tags: rational-numbers

The naive [height function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_function#Naive_height) of a rational number $x=\cfrac{m}{n}$ (in lowest terms) is defined as

$$H(x) = H\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \max\{|m|, |n|\} $$

However, $0$ can be denoted by $\frac{0}{1}, \frac{0}{2}, ...$

Then what's the value of $H(0)$?
Is it 1, or undefined?

Comment: $0/2$ is not in lowest terms.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Nice, that one went right by me.  Still, +1 for the OP, re good question.

Comment: I am surprised by the (once again anonymous) downvotes.  Personally, I was fooled until I saw David Ullrich's comment.  Anyway, the OP is asking about a definition, or interpretation, rather than asking for help solving a problem.  Therefore, I don't think that the OP is required to *show work* here.  In fact, even without the downvotes, I would still have upvoted, re the OP's thoughtfulness in raising the question.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for your answer. Would you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems silly to post this as an "answer", but the OP asked me to do so.

The apparent ambiguity is resolved by noting that $0/2$ is not in lowest terms. In fact $\text{gcd}(0,2)=2$, while $\text{gcd}(0,1)=1$; so the height of $0$ is $1$.